# Create dict from a pandas dataframe with values as tuple

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2], ['a', 'b']]), columns=['col1', 'col2'])
>>> df
  col1 col2
0    1    2
1    a    b
```

What I am trying to do is to create a dict from this dataframe where row index is the key and col1 and col2 are a value in a tuple form for my dict. Here is what I am doing but this returns a list:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df.T.to_dict('list')
{0: ['1', '2'], 1: ['a', 'b']}
```

Here is what I am trying to get:

```
{0: ('1', '2'), 1: ('a', 'b')}
```

Answer (score 3):

Lets try

```
df.agg(tuple,1).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to take the dict you have apply a dict comprehension:

```
>>> {k: tuple(v) for k, v in df.T.to_dict("list").items()}
{0: ('1', '2'), 1: ('a', 'b')}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the speed but with `itertuples`

```
dict(zip(df.index, df.itertuples(index=False, name=None)))
{0: ('1', '2'), 1: ('a', 'b')}
```

Or

```
dict(zip(df.index,map(tuple,df.values)))
```